Calendar for school's events
For our school management we're looking for a calendar app, similar to Google Calendar, with the following features:

easily to embed in HTML/PHP pages (not interested in "private links")
free or with an affordable price (best as one-time payment)
supporting multiple calendars with filters
backend (or at least API) to add and edit events, the frontend should be read-only
optimized for both desktop and mobile browsers (at least a responsive design)

As far as I know:

Google Calendar cannot provide an easy way to embed the Calendars in other web pages, nor to public share the Calendars in read-only mode
same applies for Proton Calendar

To provide more information, the goal is to allow the families to be aware of the school's events, organized in different calendars (i.e. meetings, holidays, conferences...). Of course the viewers can only see the events but only the staff (using the backend) can create and edit the events.
